Generalization of the Schur-Zassenhaus Theorem
Let $G$ be a finite group and let $N \unlhd G$. The conjugacy part of the Schur-Zassenhaus theorem states that, if $G = HN = KN$, with $H \cap N = K \cap N = 1$ (and $(|H|, |N|) = (|K|, |N|) = 1$), then $H$ and $K$ are $G$-conjugate. My question is whether we can drop the assumption that the intersections equal the trivial group. More precisely:

Let $G$ be a finite group, let $N \unlhd G$ and let $G = HN = KN$, with $H, K \leq G$ such that $H \cap N = K \cap N$. Is it true that $H$ and $K$ are $G$-conjugate?

My guess is that this is false as currently stated, but I don't know how to search for counterexamples in GAP...
If my hypothesis is true and the stated version is incorrect, are there any known generalizations of this sort, perhaps with some more hypotheses (such as $K, H$ being $p$-groups, $G$ being solvable, etc)?
Thanks in advance!

It's not even true that $H$ and $K$ are isomorphic: take $G=S_5$, $N=A_5$, $H$ cyclic of order $6$ and $K$ a copy of $S_3$. Careful choices ensure $H\cap N=K\cap N$ is the same order $3$ subgroup.

Actually, I want to add that the original statement you quote is not true either: take $G$ to be elementary Abelian of order $4$, and let $N,H,K$ be the non-trivial subgroups of order $2$. So the coprimeness in the S-Z hypotheses is crucial.

@SteveD Yes, of course... sorry, I forgot to add it...

Consider the quaternion group $Q_8=\langle i,j,k\rangle$ and let $N=\langle i\rangle\unlhd G$, $H=\langle j\rangle$, $K=\langle k\rangle$. Then $G=HN=KN$ and $H\cap N=K\cap N=\{1,-1\}$, but $H$ and $K$ are not $G$-conjugate since these subgroups are normal in $G$.

Thank you! Since the counterexample is very well-behaved, I presume such a generalization would be hard to formulate…
